# How to scroll an EditText to the very top of the layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, scrollview, android-softkeyboard

So I have this layout with some ChipsInput inside a scrollview and I simply want these to go to the very top when the keyboard is activated

I've tried to change windowSoftInputMode to adjustPan and others but it does not make it to go to the very top, just doesn't cover it.

Here's my xml layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background1"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="12dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fontFamily="@font/quattrocento"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="@string/profile"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor1"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btUpdate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_right_icon" />

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:targetApi="o">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/quattrocento"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/gallery"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor2"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:baselineAligned="false">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/close1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_close"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:elevation="7dp"
                    android:visibility="invisible"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/add1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_add"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:elevation="7dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/photo1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="115dp"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect_primary_dark"
                    android:elevation="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/close2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_close"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:elevation="7dp"
                    android:visibility="invisible"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/add2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_add"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:elevation="7dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/photo2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="115dp"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect_primary_dark"
                    android:elevation="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/close3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_close"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:elevation="7dp"
                    android:visibility="invisible"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/add3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_add"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:elevation="7dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/photo3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="115dp"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect_primary_dark"
                    android:elevation="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="12dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="5dp"
            android:background="@color/black" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/quattrocento"
                android:text="@string/about_me"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor2"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@color/white">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:maxLength="500"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:importantForAutofill="no"
                    android:autofillHints="no"
                    tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/caracCounter"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/quattrocento"
                    android:text="500"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="end" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/quattrocento"
                android:text="@string/interest1"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor2"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/categories1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <com.pchmn.materialchips.ChipsInput
            android:id="@+id/chipsInput1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            app:chip_deletable="true"
            app:chip_hasAvatarIcon="false"
            app:hint="#"
            app:chip_backgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:chip_deleteIconColor="@color/black"
            app:chip_labelColor="@color/black"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/quattrocento"
                android:text="@string/interest2"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor2"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/categories2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <com.pchmn.materialchips.ChipsInput
            android:id="@+id/chipsInput2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            app:chip_deletable="true"
            app:chip_hasAvatarIcon="false"
            app:hint="#"
            app:chip_backgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:chip_deleteIconColor="@color/black"
            app:chip_labelColor="@color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btLogout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_margin="25dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="12dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/quattrocento"
            android:text="@string/logout"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:onClick="logout"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I simply need it to be sent to the very top of the layout so my filterable list will appear when the user start to type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout) as your root and [NestedScrolView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView) in it .

**CoordinatorLayout** as root reacts to keyboard and  scrolls  your layout to the top of your phone with  assistant of **NestedScrollView**  which your **NestedScrollView** includes your layout code .

To put the issue into perspective view

**CoordinaterLayout > NestedScrolView > yourLayout**

Change your layout **XMl** like code below

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/background1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- rest of your layout xml code-->

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah, that did the trick. Thanks, I'm actually gonna study more about all types of layouts

Comment: a complement for this question. Why this same structure does not work in a fragment?