# How to setup a layout with ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-linearlayout, android-design-library

I am learning Android and right now I have an issue with the `ScrollView`.

I am using `ScrollView` as the main container of the layout with a `LinearLayout` as a child because I would like my screens support portrait and landscape orientation but this is not working as I want.

As you can see in the images below, space before the image doesn't appear, even the image is cut because the keyboard push up the layout and it doesn't fit to screen, as well in landscape orientation.

Could anyone help me about how to set up a Layout to support scrolling without losing the original design of the layout?

**Code of the layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            tools:context=".LoginActivity"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="30dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sign_in_logo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/trivia_wars_logo"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:rotation="-8"
                android:scaleX="0.75"
                android:scaleY="0.75"
                android:padding="5dp"/>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/sign_in_input_layout_username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/sign_in_input_username"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_email_username"
                    style="@style/EditTextStyle"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"/>

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/sign_in_input_layout_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/PasswordInputLayoutStyle"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/sign_in_input_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_password"
                    style="@style/EditTextStyle"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"/>

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/sign_in_action_btn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:paddingTop="12dp"
                android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                style="@style/RoundedButtonStyle"
                android:text="@string/sign_in"/>

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/sign_in_sign_up_btn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="12dp"
                android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                style="@style/OutlineRoundedButtonStyle"
                android:text="@string/sign_up"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Preview of the layout:**

[image: Preview of the layout]

**Layout tested in my device:**

[image: ![Portrait layout with active keyboard]

[image: Landscape layout]

Thanks.

Comment: As you use scroll view so whenever keyboard open it move layout to up automatically.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to handle the space before the image when the keyboard is open @Madhav

Comment: as i see in last image your focus is on password field. can you please remove it and check weather scroll available or not

Comment: also try to add margin to 'sign_in_logo' this as top margin only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to scroll an EditText to the very top of the layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57747479/how-to-scroll-an-edittext-to-the-very-top-of-the-layout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

in manifest file inside your activity.

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

</activity>
```

You will find the information about [windowSoftInputMode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element)

Answer (score 1):

Change your **LinearLayout** Property

**`android:gravity="center"`**

instead of

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

It will work..